# Image resolution, scaling / zooming in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, 2d, scaling, zooming

I need a scalable world map in my game that the player should be able to zoom into. This, however, requires a very large image or a vector graphic, or else the player is able to see the pixels when zoomed in. Both solutions seriously slow down the performance of the game, especially during rescaling. I guess there isn't a solution, but if there is, please let me know.

Comment: Do it the way any online maps do it. Have set zoom level, with a set of map tiles for each level. Save them as tiles so that a user can zoom to 5x, see it at crisp 5x resolution, but only the portion of the map within their viewport is actually loaded into memory. This takes quite a bit of logic to figure out when these are in the viewport, but it works well (I've written it myself before. It's a pain, but not something a few hours can't accomplish)

Comment: Use a large image as a base to draw to a BitmapData each time a new zoom value is set, during transition from one zoom value to another do not draw but simply scale your map screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-creating-a-tile-map-engine--gamedev-10900

Cheers,